# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException appears while starting Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, custom-adapter, getview

This is a block of code inside my ListView Customized Adapter :

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final MovieEntity feedItem=feedTrailersList.get(i);

    //LinearLayout Trailers_Linear=(LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Trailers_Linear);

    View view=convertView;
    if (view==null){
        view=LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.trailer_list_item, parent,false);
    }
    TextView trailerName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.trailer_name);
    trailerName.setText(feedItem.getTRAILER_NAME_STRING());
    trailerName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(String.valueOf(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(feedItem.getTRAILER_KEY_STRING()));
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
 return view;
}
```

Here, i am trying to startActivity via my Context, as i am in a cutomized adapter class not in an activity, but it gives me this error titles :

```
ex: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
cause : android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

i was using `Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);` flag, and tried `Intent intent=new Intent(String.valueOf(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));`
after it displayed this exception.

Can anybody tell my what does this exception refers to, your aid is completely, and respectively appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is my block of current Intent Code now, and it's working

```
Intent intent=new Intent(); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);     
intent.setData(Uri.parse(feedItem.getTRAILER_KEY_STRING())); 
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `mContext` variable is not an `Activity` - perhaps you are using `getApplicationContext()` to create `mContext`.

In any case, there's no need to have a `Context` variable at all - you can use `getContext()` at any point to retrieve the current `Context`.

Comment: This is my block of current Intent Code now, and it's working 

Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(feedItem.getTRAILER_KEY_STRING()));
                getContext().startActivity(intent);

Comment: You could have just used `getContext()` like I suggested. As long as that is an `Activity`, you don't need the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` line at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is your mContext. But you can always take proper context from `parent.getContext()`. Also your intent looks weird. It should crash with `ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent`.

Intent flag should be used like so:

```
Inten intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
...
```

Comment: This is my block of current Intent Code now, and it's working Intent intent=new Intent(); intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); intent.setData(Uri.parse(feedItem.getTRAILER_KEY_STRING())); getContext().startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter constructor, it is essential to initialize the mContext variable. When incorporating this adapter into an activity, it is imperative to supply the context of that activity. Alternatively, you can utilize the `this` keyword to furnish the necessary context.